# Rebus #18 was in a hurry to get posted

Tags: rebus

This one might drive you up a wall... ;)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this...

> <strike>an ear wrecker or loud noise?</strike> erector

because

> ear + wreck + oar

Comment: yeah but that is not an *** it is a paddle.

Comment: Well it made sense! (I think…)

Comment: @Yout Ried:  you're 99% there.  Say those words outloud, and  you'll  guess the answer. :)

Comment: Yes, your edited version is it!

Comment: I think i'm about to hit the daily limit if the association bonus counts…

Comment: @YoutRied It doesn't

Comment: @YoutRied:  I have no idea what those things are...

Comment: @Wordster It is if you have enough reputation on a number of sites, you get +100 reputation for each site you are on, and if you join a new site, you start with 101 rep

Comment: @PotatoLatte:  Ohhh!  Thanx 4 that.  There's SOOOO much to learn about this site!

Comment: @Wordster I agree! I didn't know what it was until ten minutes ago either :)

Comment: @Wordster I only know because I got it myself a while ago :) P.S. It looks like you already have it, based on your superuser account